# p:commandButton action not performed when located in conditionally rendered container

Tags: jsf, primefaces, action, el, commandbutton

I have a p:commandButton with an action attribute assigned located in a p:panelGroup which is conditionally rendered. The action method is not fired if I'm pressing the button.

If I remove the rendered attribute of the surrounding p:panelGroup (so it's always rendered) the action method is called. I don't want to assign a rendered attribute to every single element inside my form - I just want to show/hide the whole p:panelGroup. Is this possible? If yes, what can I do to get it working?

```
<h:panelGroup id="neues-verfahren-panelgroup" rendered="#{verfahrenTree.currentType.equals('neues-verfahren')}"
    styleClass="form-container">

    <h:form id="form-neues-verfahren">

        <!-- form data goes here ... -->

        <div class="form-row">
            <p:commandButton id="form-neues-verfahren-speichern" action="#{verfahrenBean.neuesVerfahrenSpeichern}" value="Speichern" />
        </div>

    </h:form>

</h:panelGroup>
```

**Edit (Solved):**
Changing the scope of the backing bean from request scoped to view scoped solved the problem.

Comment: Tried moving the form so it wraps the panel? D please post jsf and PF version

Comment: If the form wraps the panel I get a ComponentNotFoundException. What do you mean with JSF and PF version?

Comment: Then correct the update references...

Comment: There is nothing to update. The IDs haven't changed.

Comment: Then your exception cannot be explained by the code you show (at least not by me)... [mcve] please. And post **what** component cannot be found

Comment: Check #9 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Comment: You were right - there was an update reference I needed to remove. Now the exception is gone and the form wraps the panelGroup. Followed #9 of your link and added `<f:ajax render=":form-neues-verfahren"></f:ajax>` to my p:commandButton. Now the form is submitted two times but the action method still not gets executed.